# What is mean by active element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While going through Ruby docs for Selenium WebDriver :
http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/TargetLocator.html#active_element-instance_method

I came across method active_element which gets active element. But I didn't understand what is mean by active element? Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it's not in the Ruby doc, but in C# and Java's documentation here is how `active element` is defined. [Source here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/ITargetLocator.cs).

```
the element that currently has the focus, or the body element if no element with focus can be detected.
```

[Java source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.java) further says

```
This matches the semantics of calling "document.activeElement" in Javascript.
```